# How should I do to be able to ask a yes or no question in C

Tags: c, char, boolean

I'm trying to make my code to... I guess recognize if I am pressing "y" or "n", and and do stuff depending on which one is in the input.

I thought it would be this simple, but unfortunately it isn't.

How am I supposed to do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
 {
    char y;

    printf("Single provider (y/n)? ");
    scanf(" %c", &y);

    if (y == '121' || y == '89')
    {
        printf("single");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("not single");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Need to change `scanf(" %c", &y);` to `scanf("%c", &y);` otherwise you have to enter one spcae before entering the character.

Comment: Use `y == 121` with no single quotes

Comment: @AhmadYeaseenKhan Thx for answer, butt it still doesn't work and I'm still getting thje waring "yn.c:10:14: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   10 |     if (y == '121' || y == '89')"... I'd actually like to use the bool operator, but don't know how... any idea?

Comment: @mousetail I hope you mean , `y==121`

Comment: @mousetail That worked. thx.

Any idea about how I could do the same thing with bool?

Comment: @DimitriMikhalev no idea what you mean by that

Comment: Don't use magic numbers, but `if(y == 'y' || y == 'Y')`

Comment: @AhmadYeaseenKhan that space does not mean you have to enter a space to match it. It's purpose is to filter any amount of whitespace *if the user entered any* and is a typical use with `%c` or `%[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main(void)
 {
    int y;

    printf("Single provider (y/n)? ");
    do
    {
        y = fgetc(stdin);
    }while(y != EOF && y != 'y' && y != 'n');

    if(y != EOF)
        if (y == 'y')
        {
            printf("single");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("not single");  
        }
 }
```

Comment: looks nice and all, but what do these things mean? :D hah... fgetc(stdin), OEF... ty anyway.. I'll need to look in to these things before I can use it tho...

Comment: @DimitriMikhalev yes you need to look into it ...

Comment: could I get the input for y with scanf instead or... how does this work??

Comment: why do I need to check for if y is not "end of file"?

Comment: @DimitriMikhalev you need to check for EOF when you call fgetc because that is one of the things that it can return. This can happen when, say for example, someone redirected stdin to a file rather than the console or you pressed the end of transmission key for your terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You are making a beautiful mix-up here: apparently have heard about ASCII codes and you want to apply them into your code. The idea is good, not the realisation:

Your code:

```
if (y == '121' || y == '89')
```

Correct code (without ASCII codes):

```
if (y == 'y' || y == 'Y')
```

Correct code (using ASCII codes):

```
if (y == 121 || y == 89) // ASCII_Code('Y')=89 and ASCII('y')=121
```

(Please don't remove the comment, it's very useful for readability)

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

> How should I do to be able to ask a yes or no question in C

There are 5 input sets to distinguish:

1. `"Y\n"` or something  similar: `"y\n"`, `"Yes\n"`, `"YES\n"` ...
2. `"N\n"` or something  similar: `"n\n"`, `"no\n"`, ...
3. End-of-file occurs.  `scanf()` returns `EOF` and `feof(stdin)`is true.
4. Input error occurs.  `scanf()` returns `EOF` and `ferror(stdin)`is true. (Rare)
5. Something else.  Usually a user mistake.

In general, best to avoid `scanf()`and use `fgets()`.
Yet sticking with `scanf()`:

Read in a line of input.  Use a space to consume leading white-spaces including a prior line's `'\n'`.

```
unsigned char buf[80];
buf[0] = 0;
int retval = scanf(" %79[^\n]", buf);
```

Then disambiguate.  Suggest case insensitivity. Perhaps allow just the first letter or the whole word.

```
if (retval == EOF) {
  if (feof(stdin) {
    puts("End-of-file");
  } else { // Input error expected
    puts("Input error");
  }
} else {
  for (unsigned char *s = buf; *s; s++) {
    *s = tolower(*s);
  }
  if (strcmp(buf, "y") == 0 || strcmp(buf, "yes") == 0) {
    puts("Yes");
  } else if (strcmp(buf, "n") == 0 || strcmp(buf, "no") == 0) {
    puts("No");
  } else {
    puts("Non- yes/no input");
  }
}
```

---

How about a helper function to handle Yes/No, True/False, ....?

```
// Return first character on match
// Return 0 on no match
// Return EOF on end-of-file or input error
int Get1of2(const char *prompt, const char *answer1, const char *answer2) {
  if (prompt) {
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
  }
  unsigned char buf[80];
  buf[0] = 0;
  int retval = scanf(" %79[^\n]", buf);
  if (retval == EOF) {
    return EOF;
  }
  for (unsigned char *s = buf; *s; s++) {
    *s = tolower(*s);
  }
  if ((buf[0] ==  answer1[0] && buf[1] == 0) || 
      strcmp(buf, answer1) == 0) {
    return buf[0];
  }
  if ((buf[0] ==  answer2[0] && buf[1] == 0) || 
      strcmp(buf, answer2) == 0) {
    return buf[0];
  }
  return 0;  // None of the above.
}
```

Sample calls:

```
int yn = Get1of2("Single provider (y/n)? ", "yes", "no");
int rb = Get1of2("What is your favorite color? (r/b)? ", "red", "blue");
int tf = Get1of2("Nineveh the capital of Assyria? (t/f)? ", "true", "false");
```

Comment: thx... this is definitely over my head for now, but could certainly come in handy in the future :)